# Calculate the volume of a right prism with the base of a right triangle

Tags: geometry

I was trying to solve this problem but I came to the conclusion that the right angled triangle is not possible to be calculated. The problem is as follows:

The base of a right prism with a height of 150 mm is a right-angled triangle, where one leg is 45 mm long. The area of its largest face is 5850 mm^2. Calculate the volume of the prism.

When I tried calculating it I always came to the conclusion that there might be a mistake in the problem but then I am unsure how to calculate this.

hypotenuse^2 = 2025 + 260^2, hypotenuse = 259.
Volume = Base Area x Height
Volume = 5850 x 150
Volume = 877500 mm^3 - I find that strange.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is something wrong in the problem. The area of the face corresponding to the 45mm leg is $45\cdot 150=6750\ mm^2$, which is greater than $5850\ mm^2$. Also, I have no idea when you got the 260 number, or how you got your hypotenuse to be less than that.

Comment: Thank you, it makes no sense with the "largest" face not actually being the largest. The teacher made a mistake, so I wanted to be sure.